# List Assignment Index out of range error in array-code

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
k = int(input("Enter the number of elements in the list: "))
n = []
for i in range(k):
    n[i] = int(input(str(i+1) + " = "))
    print(n[i])
```

This is a code to take in the desired number of elements with the desired length of the list (array). The print(n[i]) was put in to simply check whether this step is reached. But the error occurs before this and states that the list assignment index, which, i assume, is 'i', is out of range.
Why?

Comment: Because that element does not exist (the list is empty), can you use `.append` to add elements to the list? You could change an element in the list if it existed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `n` is initialized with size 0. When you assign `n[1]` to some value ,it gives you index out of range error. Try to use `append` instead.

```py
k = int(input("Enter the number of elements in the list: "))
n = []
for i in range(k):
    n.append(int(input(str(i+1) + " = ")))
    print(n[i])
```

Comment: Lovely! I understand it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Over here if you are trying to append (add) to your list that in your case is `n` you have to use append instead of `n[i]` . When you use `n[i]` you are actually assigning a value and not adding a new value.

The below snippet is using appending method.

```
k = int(input("Enter the number of elements in the list: "))
n = []
for i in range(k):
    n.append(int(input(str(i+1) + " = ")))
    print(n[i])
```

If you want to still solve using assignment to the list values you can also do this.

```
k = int(input("Enter the number of elements in the list: "))
n = [None] * k
for i in range(k):
    n[i] = int(input(str(i+1) + " = "))
    print(n[i])
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I got it